# GSON parsing error while parsing String to hashmap

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I am trying to parse a string using Gson

```
String str = "{key=sample value}";
new Gson().fromJson(str, HashMap.class())
```

I am getting a JSONSyntax exception for this. If I change the string to "{key=samplevalue}" it works fine(removed space). Can anyone please explain. What should be done so that I get hashmap as "key" = "sample value"

Comment: Try adding escape character **\"** in your string. I.e. `"{\"key\"=\"sample value\"}"`

Answer (score 1):

In [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/), both *key* and *value* (if it's of type string) must be double quoted. So, in your example the valid JSON is:

```
{"key":"sample value"}
```

which in Java, `"` should be escaped:

```
String str = "{\"key\":\"sample value\"}";
```

Comment: Besides that, the key/value separator is colon, not equals.  `{"key" : "value"}`

Answer (score 0):

your code does not compile

you would have to replace *class()* with *class*
it would be necessary to improve the JSON format it would be necessary to improve the JSON format by adding quotes and an apostrophe

```
String str = "{'key'='sample value'}";
HashMap hashMap = new Gson().fromJson(str, HashMap.class);
System.out.println(hashMap);  /// ===> {key=sample value}
```

or

```
String str = "{\"key\":\"sample value\"}";;
HashMap hashMap = new Gson().fromJson(str, HashMap.class);
System.out.println(hashMap);  /// ===> {key=sample value}
```

now is working

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html#parsing-json-into-java-objects